# Как в AndroidStudio включить выбор виртуального устройства?

Tags: java, android-studio

Включены два виртуальных устройства через GenyMotion.
Если пару раз запускаешь программу через один из них, то потом выбор устройства пропадает. Как вернуть выбор устройства и вообще отключить запоминание последнего выбранного?

Answer (score 1):

При запуске приложения появляется окно с выбором устройства, на котором это приложение можно запустить (эмуляторы и физические устройства). Если в этом окне поставить галочку «use same selection for future launches», то последующие запуски приложения будут производится на выбранном устройстве.

**Чтобы поменять устройство**, необходимо зайти в меню `Run` – `Edit configurations` и на вкладке `General` снять галочку с «use same selection for future launches».

Comment: Галочка была снята. Где-то должен быть выбор на каком устройстве запускать.

Comment: Вопрос все еще актуален. Если три раза запускаешь на одном и том же устройстве, AndroidStudio больше не предлагает выбор, что неудобно. Галка снята. Как еще можно попробовать решить?